# How to exclude a dependecy only for test scope in java

Tags: java, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I want to exclude a dependency only for test scope.

Example:-

commons-lang3 dependency is used in two different places in my project. I want to exclude this dependency for test scope only.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

How can I do so ?

Comment: Why? What harm does this library do in tests?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I have my custom dependencie which I want to exclude only for test

Answer (score 5):

you can configure the `classpath` at surefire plugin.
like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>xxx</version>
    <configuration>
      <classpathDependencyExcludes>
        <classpathDependencyExclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</classpathDependencyExclude>
      </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

for more information [Removing Dependency Classpath Elements](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html)

Comment: Won't that allways exclude the commons-lang3 dependency, irrespective of build scope?

Comment: @ 911DidBush the surefire plugin play a role only at test scope, so it exclude commons-lang3 dependency only at test scope.